# Hibernate ignores @GeneratedValue when creating schema on Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I use Spring Boot 2.6.1, Hibernate 5.6.1 and Postgresql 14.1 on docker. I have an entity called person that extends a base entity class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The problem is when Hibernate creates my schema on Postgresql it ignores the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) and creates a simple column with no auto increment or identity mechanism. So the query

```
    INSERT INTO person(name) VALUES('Bob')
```

executes with error.
ERROR:  null value in column "id" of relation "person" violates not-null constraint

Comment: Try to use `@Generated Value(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` by default this as per JPA doc this generation use autoincrement and asign a value to a database e begin to use  `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`

Comment: I've tried all IDENTITY, TABLE and SEQUENCE still nothing happened.